# orthogonal polynomials with respect to $\exp(-ax)$?

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials

I know that the Laguerre polynomials are orthogonal with respect to $\exp(-x)$, but is there an orthogonal set with respect to $\exp(-ax)$? Is it possible to extend the Laguerre polynomials to obtain orthogonality/orthonormality with respect to this slightly changed weight?

What I would like to do is to find polynomials $\{P_i(x)\}$ such that $\langle P_i(x)\exp(-a_i\; x) | P_j(x)\exp(-a_j\;x)\rangle$ is orthonormal.

Comment: Hint: if $a > 0$, do a change of variables in $\int_0^\infty f(x) g(x) e^{-ax}\ dx$

Comment: Maybe if you first try Gram--Schmidt to get a set of orthogonal polynomials, then notice how they're related to the standard Laguerre polynomials with $a=1$, you can quickly conjecture the answer to your question and then prove it.

Comment: You need to provide an interval as well.  Say: orthogonal with respect to $\exp(-ax)$ on $[0,+\infty)$ or something like that.

Comment: @GEdgar : You're right that Laubert515 needs to put that there.  I overlooked it since "everybody [?] knows" that that's what you do when you think about Laguerre polynomials.

Comment: I have tried gram-schmidt and it is nearly impossible. I can get the coefficients of the first 2 functions in about an hour, but the third took 40+ hours on mathematica with a 3.1 GHz machine.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Do you know how that would work or are you just saying that is an idea?

Comment: Are the $a_i$ given in advance?

Comment: Yes, I know how it works (for $\exp(-ax)$, not for $\exp(-a_j x)$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is, OP really should remember that specifying just the weight function doesn't cut it, seeing that the inner product involves a **definite** integral, and thus a *support interval* is very much needed to completely specify the inner product involved in constructing the orthogonal polynomials involved. To use the Laguerre polynomials as an example, the weight function is $\exp(-x)$, and the support interval is $[0,\infty)$, corresponding to the inner product

$$\langle f,g\rangle=\int_0^\infty \exp(-u)f(u)g(u)\mathrm du$$

and we have the Laguerre polynomials $L_n(x)$ satisfying $\langle L_j,L_k\rangle=\delta_{j,k}$.

Now... as already hammered to you in the comments, since

$$\int_0^\infty \exp(-au)f(u)g(u)\mathrm du=\frac1{a}\int_0^\infty \exp(-v)f(v/a)g(v/a)\mathrm dv$$

**assuming** that your support interval is indeed $[0,\infty)$, building up your "modified" Laguerre polynomials shouldn't be too hard.

Otherwise, there is always the Stieltjes procedure for generating orthogonal polynomials from a given inner product. I already described it at length [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/77595), and I'd rather not repeat myself. All I'll say is that the procedure generates *monic* orthogonal polynomials; you'll have to figure it out on your own if you require a different normalization for your polynomials. In this regard,

$$\int_0^\infty \exp(-au)u^k\mathrm du=\frac{k!}{a^{k+1}}$$

will be a useful identity for you.

---

If the support interval is not $[0,\infty)$, but some finite interval $[r,s]$; that is, the inner product involved is

$$\langle f,g\rangle_{a,[r,s]}=\int_r^s \exp(-au)f(u)g(u)\mathrm du$$

the Stieltjes procedure is still useful, but one now needs the identity

$$\int_r^s \exp(-au)u^k\mathrm du=\frac{\Gamma(k+1,ar)-\Gamma(k+1,as)}{a^{k+1}}$$

where $\Gamma(k,a)$ is the upper incomplete gamma function. In *Mathematica*, one could compactly express the right hand side of that last identity as `Gamma[k + 1, a r, a s]/(a^(k+1))`, making use of *Mathematica*'s support for incomplete gamma functions with arbitrary integration limits.