# How to work out orthogonal polynomials for regression model

Tags: regression, orthogonal-polynomials

I put this question here as it has a pure maths element to it, even though it has a statistical twist. Basically, I have been given the table of data:

> $$\begin{matrix} i & \mathrm{Response} \, y_i & \mathrm{Covariate} \, x_i \\ 1 & -1 & -0.5 \\ 2 & -0.25 &-0.25 \\ 3 & 1 & 0 \\ 4 & 1.2 & 0.25 \\ 5 & 2.6 & 0.5 \end{matrix}$$

And for here, I need to create an orthogonal regression model. In other words, I need to come up with a model in the form

$$Y_i = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1(ax_i + b) + \alpha_2(dx_i^2 + ex_i + f)$$

Where

$$\sum_i^n ax_i + b = dx_i^2 + ex_i + f = 0$$

and $\alpha_{0,1,2}$ are just constants.

From looking at it, I can see that the linear term can just be $x_i$ as $\sum_i^n x_i = 0$, but I'm stuck on how to solve for the quadratic bit.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

It looks as if you're using the (discrete) inner product

$$\langle f,g\rangle=\sum_j^n f(x_j) g(x_j)$$

and I'll proceed with that assumption.

The canonical method for producing a basis of orthogonal polynomials with respect to some (discrete or continuous) inner product is the *Stieltjes procedure*. I discussed the continuous case [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/77595); the discrete case proceeds similarly.

In any event, to summarize: if you have a set of *monic* orthogonal polynomials $\phi_k(x)$ satisfying the recurrence

$$\phi_{k+1}(x)=(x+b_k)\phi_k(x)+c_k\phi_{k-1}(x)$$

with the associated orthogonality condition $\langle \phi_j,\phi_k\rangle=0,\quad j\neq k$ and the initial values $\phi_{-1}(x)=0$ and $\phi_0(x)=1$, the recurrence coefficients $b_k$ and $c_k$ are obtained through the formulae

$$\begin{align*}b_k&=-\frac{\langle x\phi_k ,\phi_k\rangle}{\langle \phi_k,\phi_k\rangle}\\c_k&=-\frac{\langle\phi_k,\phi_k\rangle}{\langle\phi_{k-1},\phi_{k-1}\rangle}\end{align*}$$

where $x\phi_k$ denotes the product of $x$ and $\phi_k(x)$.

For this particular case, as you say, $\phi_1(x)=x$ is easily determined; thus, to compute $\phi_2(x)$,  we compute $b_1=0$ and $c_1=-\frac18$ to yield $\phi_2(x)=x^2-\frac18$.

We can then determine that the quadratic least-squares fit to the data is (approximately) given by $0.71+3.46\phi_1(x)+0.285714\phi_2(x)$.

If you want more details on data-fitting with orthogonal polynomials, see [this article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0105007) by George Forsythe. You might also want to look up the *Gram polynomials*, which are the standard orthogonal polynomials used for data fitting when the data has equispaced abscissas.

Comment: Could you help with this similar question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1832979/two-dimensional-discrete-orthogonal-polynomials-for-regression please?