# Two dimensional (discrete) orthogonal polynomials for regression

Tags: regression, orthogonal-polynomials

This question [How to work out orthogonal polynomials for regression model](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279608/how-to-work-out-orthogonal-polynomials-for-regression-model) and the answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/354807/51020 explain how to build orthogonal polynomials for regression. However they only consider one dimensional functions.

How can we use (discrete) orthogonal polynomials for regression with two dimensional functions (i.e., $z = f(x, y)$)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In three dimensions, we have the spherical harmonics, a polynomial set orthogonal over the unit sphere.

http://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/SphericalHarmonicY/

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalHarmonic.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics

In two dimensions, we have the Zernike polynomials, orthogonal over the unit disk.

http://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/ZernikeR/

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ZernikePolynomial.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zernike_polynomials

To answer your question via demonstration, construct the radial Zernike functions by applying the orthogonalizing method of Gram and Schmidt to the functions sequence
$$
 \left\{ r^{2k} \right\}_{k=0}^{\infty} = 
 \left\{ 1, r^{2}, r^{4}, \dots \right\} 
$$
over the interval $0\le r < 1$ with monic normalization $(R(r)=1)$. The result is the set of rotationally invariant Zernike polynomials
$$
 \left\{ R^{0}_{2k}(r) \right\}_{k=0}^{\infty} = 
 \left\{ 1, 2r^{2}-1, 6r^{4} - 6r +1, \dots \right\} 
$$
In general,
$$
R^{0}_{2k}(r) = \sum_{j=0}^{k} \left(-1\right)^{j} 
\frac{\left( 2k-j\right)!} {j!\left(\left( k-j\right)!\right)^{2}}r^{2(k-j)}
$$

The following is a cutaway diagram of the first eight terms. Notice the Fourier like quality: a constant offset term, and then functions of zero mean, with increasing frequency.

[image: cutaways]

We can expand these polynomials to account for angular variation too. The full set of Zernike polynomials follows.

Start with non-negative integers $n$ for *order* and $m$ for *angular frequency* such that $n-m$ is even. The
recursion relationship is simplified by defining the midpoint $\omega=\frac{1}{2}(n-m)$ and the average $\sigma=\frac{1}{2}(n+m)$. The full set of radial polynomials is: 
$$  
R_n^m(r) = \sum_{j=0}^{\omega}{
\left(-1\right)^j
\frac{(n-j)!}
{j!\left(\omega-j\right)!\left(\sigma-j\right)!}
r^{n-2j}}
$$
The Zernike polynomials are a product of the radial functions and the exponential term
$$
    U_n^m(r,\theta) = R_n^{m}(r)e^{i m \theta}
$$
The set complete through order $n=6$ is shown below. The order increase $n=0, 1, 2, dots$ moving down. The angular frequency increases as you move aways from the centerline.

[image: pyramid]

There are a few ways to define the unit disk,
$$
D_{2} = 
    \begin{cases}
      \left\{z\in\mathbb{C} \colon |z| \le 1\right\} \\
      \left\{\left( r, \theta \right)\in\mathbb{R}^{2} \colon 0\le r \le 1, 0 \le \theta < 2\pi\right\} \\
      \left\{\left( x, y \right)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}  \colon x^{2} + y^{2} \le 1\right\}
    \end{cases}
$$
and the first few polynomials are expressed in terms of all three coordinates.

$$
\begin{array}{cclllll}
%
 n & m & \text{Complex} && \text{Polar} && \text{Cartesian} \\\hline
%
 0 & 0 & 1 & Re: & 1 & Re: & 1 \\[2pt]
   &   &   & Im: & 0 & Im: & 0 \\[4pt]
%
  1 & 1 & z & Re: & r\cos\theta & Re: & x \\[2pt]
    &   &     & Im: & r\sin\theta & Im: & y \\[4pt]
%
  2 & 0 & 2|z|^2-1
    & Re: & 2r^{2}-1 & Re: & 2\left(x^{2} + y^{2}\right)-1 \\[2pt]
    &   &        
    & Im: & 0 & Im: & 0 \\[2pt]
  2 & 2 & z^{2} 
    & Re: & r^{2}\cos\theta & Re: & (x-y) (x+y) \\[2pt]
    &   &         
    & Im: & r^{2}\sin\theta & Im: & 2xy \\[4pt]
%
  3 & 1 & z\left(3|z|^2-2\right) 
    & Re: & \left(3r^{2}-2r\right)\cos\theta 
    & Re: & x \left(3 \left(x^2 + y^2\right) - 2\right) \\[2pt]
    &   &         
    & Im: & \left(3r^{2}-2r\right)\sin\theta 
    & Im: & y \left(3 \left(x^2 + y^2\right) - 2\right) \\[2pt]
  3 & 3 & z^{3} 
    & Re: & r^{3}\sin\theta 
    & Re: & \phantom{-}x^{3} - 3xy^{2} \\[2pt]
    &   &         
    & Im: & r^{3}\sin\theta 
    & Im: & -y^{3} + 3yx^{2} \\[4pt]
\end{array}
$$